# Plot hlines in embedded graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, embed

I'm practicing tkinter and matplotlib in this piece of code and what it is supposed to do is to embed a simple matplotlib graph into a tkinter GUI. The thing is I also want horizontal lines to be plotted in this embedded graph by mouse clicks but I'm not getting the result I want.

What I'm getting is that by the first mouse click a new plot is created outside the tkinter GUI of the same graph with one horizontal line in it (where it was clicked on). If I close this plot window that popped up and try to click again on the embedded graph a new plot pops up but this time it contains only a horizontal line.

What's going on?

The code I'm practicing on:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, frame)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

def pick(event):
    plt.ion()
    plt.hlines(event.ydata,event.xdata-0.009,event.xdata+0.009,colors='red',
           linestyle='solid')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', pick)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `plt.ion()`, call `canvas.show()` after drawing the line.

---

Moreover, following the [matplotlib embedding in tk](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) example, I wouldn't use `pyplot` but use `Figure` (which you have imported but don't use). Then your code would become:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
fig = Figure(figsize=(16,8))
p = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
p.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, frame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, frame)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

def pick(event):
    p.hlines(event.ydata, event.xdata-0.009, event.xdata+0.009,
             colors='red', linestyle='solid')
    canvas.show()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', pick)

root.mainloop()
```